# Armadillo element wise multiplication of each col in matrix1, with each col in matrix2, store in matrix3

Tags: c++, armadillo

The following loop generates the desired output, but I feel there is a more armadillo like way to produce the same result. Possible with .each_col() but I could not get it to work properly.

> mat1 =  n x 8, mat2 =  n x 8, mat3 =  n x 64,
>   arma v6.1, c++98

```
for (unsigned i= 0; i< 8; i++)
{
    for (unsigned j= 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        mat3.col(i * 8 + j) = mat1.col(i) % mat2.col(j);
    }
}
```